# non-standard evaluation to update a format with updateInputSlider: bug?

Tags: html, r, shiny, non-standard-evaluation

I have a **shiny application** that has a functionnality to translate its text between several languages, by using some RenderText and an ActionButton to toggle between languages.
 Here is my app:

```
library(shiny)
trads = list(text3=list("text3 in language 1", "text in other language"),
             titl3=list("widget label in language 1", "widget label in other language"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("language",label="language", icon=icon("flag")),
  htmlOutput("text3", container = tags$h3),
  sliderInput("slider1", label=h2("slider1"), 0, 10, 5)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


     tr <- function(text){sapply(text, function(s) trads[[s]][[input$language%%2+1]], USE.NAMES=FALSE)}

     output$text3 = renderText({tr("text3")})

     observeEvent(input$language, {
          updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", label=tr("titl3"))
     })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works fine except that my slider label was formatted initially with a html tag `h3()`, and when I use `updatesliderinput` I loose this tag and it returns to plain text. I tried adding the tag in the translation with `paste0`, or different syntax with `eval` but it prints in text the result of the paste instead of running it or gives an error.
Any ideas to translate while keepping the format? Thanks

Note: I have the same problem with one text containing a URL link..

Comment: Have you tried with `label=h3(tr("titl3"))` ?

Comment: i just tried, it displays "[object Object]' instead of the translation :-(

Comment: Ok what about `label = h3(trads[["titl3"]][[input$language%%2+1]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it really seams you have found a bug in `updateSliderInput` here. It can only handle pure strings and no HTML tags. As a work around would I recommend you to add something like this to the beginning of your UI

```
tags$head(
    tags$style(
      'label[for = "slider1"] {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    }'
    )
  )
```

but change the css to what ever you like (maybe copy the css rules for the h2 tag) and then always only pass a string to the label parameter.  This way the styling always stays the same.

my complete code

```
library(shiny)
trads = list(text3=list("text3 in language 1", "text in other language"),
             titl3=list("widget label in language 1", "widget label in other language"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      'label[for = "slider1"] {
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    }'
    )
  ),
  actionButton("language",label="language", icon=icon("flag")),
  htmlOutput("text3", container = tags$h3),
  sliderInput("slider1", label="slider1", 0, 10, 5)

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  tr <- function(text){sapply(text, function(s) trads[[s]][[input$language%%2+1]], USE.NAMES=FALSE)}

  output$text3 = renderText({tr("text3")})

  observeEvent(input$language, {
    updateSliderInput(session, "slider1", label=tr("titl3"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: just one question: what happens if , say, i have already a css stylesheet defining global slider styles. Will this override the default style?

Comment: I think this rule will overwrite since it is more specific. But only where they overlap. Else the combination will be used. But I'm no CSS expert.